# Using the COALESCE and IN keywords in the same sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, coalesce

I want to select results from a database that selects records depending on if they exist in a parameter using the `IN` keyword:

```
SELECT * FROM report_view
WHERE project_id = 1
AND versionName IN (SELECT LTRIM(string) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT FROM [dbo].[func_ParseString](@milestoneInput))
```

this works fine but I want to use the `COALESCE` keyword to bring back everything if nothing is returned in the IN statement.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `COALESCE` to replace a NULL in a *single column* with a given value. Use `NOT EXISTS` to specify no a no-row condition in a result table. It looks like what you want is:

```
SELECT * FROM report_view
WHERE project_id = 1
AND (
    versionName IN (
        SELECT LTRIM(string) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT 
        FROM [dbo].[func_ParseString](@milestoneInput)
    )
    OR NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM report_view
        WHERE project_id = 1
        AND versionName IN (
            SELECT LTRIM(string) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT 
            FROM [dbo].[func_ParseString](@milestoneInput)
        )
    )
)
```

I am not sure how many times this is going to call your function though. You might be better off with something like the following, using a `UNION ALL` instead of `OR`:

```
;WITH VersionNames AS (
    SELECT LTRIM(string) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS versionName
    FROM [dbo].[func_ParseString](@milestoneInput)
)
SELECT *
FROM report_view
WHERE project_id = 1
AND versionName IN (SELECT versionName from VersionNames)
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM report_view
WHERE project_id = 1 
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM report_view
    WHERE project_id = 1
    AND versionName IN (SELECT versionName from VersionNames)
)
```

I am not sure whether using the CTE simply amounts to syntactic sugar or actually forces the function to be only evaluated once though; someone else can investigate this and provide a proper answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative that puts all the logic in an `exists` clause.

The idea is to use window functions to see if there is any match as well as determining if a particular string is a match.

```
SELECT *
FROM report_view 
WHERE project_id = 1 and
      exists (select 1
              from (SELECT sum(case when ltrim(ps.string) = rv.VersionName then 1 else 0
                               end) over () as NumMatches,
                           (case when ltrim(ps.string) = rv.VersionName then 1 else 0
                            end) as IsMatch
                    FROM [dbo].[func_ParseString](@milestoneInput) ps
                   ) t
              where IsMatch = 1 or NumMatchs = 0
             )
```

The key is the `where` clause which says to return true when either the value matches or there are no matches in the list.